# How do I install a package in Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, openssl, dependencies, debian-etch

How do I install a package in Debian via SSH? In my case I'm looking to install OpenSSL, but the instructions could be for installing any other package as well.

UPDATE: I did run into some issues while attempting to install OpenSSL (package dependencies). For an answer on how to (clear package dependency issues) while installing packages in Debian, please refer to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/414893/73145) answer.

Comment: Simple questions help people whose primary role is not system administration. It also helps the advanced users of this site by generating the search engine hits and page views required to sustain ServerFault. Not sure why the down votes.

Comment: Probably because the question doesn't display *any* research effort.  If you had answered your own question you probably wouldn't have received any downvotes.

Comment: I did research and did find the answer on other sites. I just wanted to put a very simple QA question on SF, that's what this site is for. And I also wanted someone else to get the points for answering it. I don't see any problem with that? "Probably because the question doesn't display any research effort" is an assumption. But OK. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apt-get](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) or [dpkg](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg)

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

or

```
dpkg -i package-file-name
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install packagename`

In your case

`sudo apt-get install openssl`, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look into [Aptitude](http://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude), a mildly more modern alternative. Or [Synaptic](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/), if you want a full GUI.

```
sudo aptitude install somepackage
```

Or for interactive mode:

```
sudo aptitude
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PKGPATH="$(apt-cache show openssl |grep ^Filename: |sed 's/^Filename: //')"
TDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
wget -O ${TDIR}/pkg.deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian/${PKGPATH}
pushd $TDIR
ar x pkg.deb
[ -x preinst ] && ./preinst install
tar xzf -C / data.tar.gz
[ -x postinst ] && ./postinst configure
popd
rm -rf $TDIR
```

Missing error handling, cleanup, version management (including picking the correct version based on all the magic apt does and passing the correct args to maintainer scripts), but basically functional in the minimal case.